# Office network failover?

Tags: networking, high-availability, local-area-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hardware do I need to add a backup internet connection?](https://serverfault.com/questions/2058/what-hardware-do-i-need-to-add-a-backup-internet-connection)

I have a office LAN providing internet access to several workstations. Each workstation is basically connected to the hub, which is connected to the router through ethernet.

Wat I need to do is to hire another provider and enable any method to switch user's internet connection if the active connection goes down.

How can I do this?

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to relate to programming in some way.

Comment: Then, where do u recommend me to ask such a question,sorry no idea.

Comment: The answer to this question also depends on the hardware you are using.

Comment: A simple router, I need to know which hardware should I use, no idea... to have it in failover

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a router that supports multi-WAN failover. There are many of them on the market - do some research and choose one. I won't get into product recommendations here since that is off-topic.

Alternatively, you can set up a pfSense box and use that as your router - it supports multi-WAN very well and is free (if you have some spare hardware to run it on).