# Howto switch ISP provider?

Tags: networking, failover, local-area-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Office network failover?](https://serverfault.com/questions/354882/office-network-failover)

I have a office LAN providing internet access to several workstations, each workstation it is basically connected to the hub that it is connected to the router through ethernet.

What I need to do is to hire another provider and enable any method to switch users internet connection if the active connection go down, but how can I do it? any suggestion?no idea, I guess I should use any specific router or hardware for the failover, anyway I don't know where to start.

Comment: Your question already got migrated here from StackOverflow - no need to re-post like this.

Comment: Whow. You still have hubs? where did you find them? Garbage bin? Not seen hubs for many many years - ever since switches are sooo cheap now.

Answer (score 0):

You need either a router/firewall that capable of detecting failure on one of the lines and switch users to the other one or workstation with Linux on it acting as the same router/firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a dual WAN router.  If you google that, you will find a lot of options that allow for failover for a reasonable price.